# Regular Expression for Beginning and End of Line

Tags: regex

I often find myself changing the delimiter of CSV files from "," to þ¶þ using the following regular expressions:

```
 s/","/þ¶þ/g
 s/^/þ/
 s/$/þ/
```

I feel like there should be a simpler way to perform this action without using 3 statements.

Any tips and tricks that can help me out?

*Note:  Since the question was asked; the reason I need to do this is because there is a popular Litigation Technology software called Concordance which uses "[ASCII value (020) or ¶ for the field seperator, ASCII value (254) or þ for the text qualifier](http://www.litsupportspecialist.com/?cat=6)" as the seperates.*

Comment: What if the file contains `1,2,"a,b\nc",6`? Why don't you like CSV, anyway? And what language are you using?- I'm sure you can find a simple CSV library.

Comment: Why on earth do you find yourself doing that?

Comment: There is no such thing as ASCII value 254.

Comment: This won't work, because CSV have weird parsing issues involving escaped quotes or commas.  You need to use a CSV module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something along this line?

```
s/","|^|$/þ/
```